# Typescript cannot find module 'lunr'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a file `src/client/main.ts` with this code :

```
import * as lunr from 'lunr';

console.log('main');
```

I have installed the dt typings for lunr `typings install dt~lunr --save --globals`

My tsconfig.json file has the following selectors :

```
"filesGlob": [
  "src/**/*.ts"
],
"files": [
  "typings/index.d.ts"
]
```

Why does not the typescript compiler find the module `lunr` ? The compiler always output `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lunr'`

Comment: What typescript version you are using? I think filesGlob is supported in nigthly builds only

Comment: Tyescript 1.8.10. I tried a bunch of others things. For example, I have a gulp script with `gulp-typescript` and I tried `gulp.src(['typings/index.d.ts', 'src/client/main.ts']).pipe(ts())` but I have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the typings for lunr, i saw that it defined a `namespace`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html

It means that it should not be used as an import but as a namespace on the global object. So my main.ts file becomes :

```
lunr(function() { console.log('do something with lunr') });

console.log('main');
```

and load the lunr library in your html file using a `script` tag before loading your own script.

I lost almost 2 hours of my time ... Sad ...

Comment: You posted this as a solution, but you did not show how you imported your 'lunr' entity into your component for use, which was the whole point of the question.  You just start using an undefined 'lunr' object.

Comment: I thought it was clear. Just load the script in your head tag without using any loader. I just edited my answer.

Comment: unfortunately not an option, if you want to use it in pure node context ...